# Angular google autologin with angularx-social-login

Tags: angular, google-signin, angular-services, angular13

i am using google sign in to verify my users with the help of angularx-social-login, login and logout is working, but i want the user to keep logged if it doesnt logout,that means, if i close a tab or the browser, the next time doesnt have to log in again. i use a guard to protect the routes that are lazily loaded.

the problem is `autologin: true` doesnt work, whenever i reload the page or open a new tab, the guard kicks me to the login page

authService

```js
  userState() {
    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.loggedIn = (user != null);
    });
  }
```

authGuard

```js
    if (!this.authService.loggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate([localUrls.login])
    }
    return true
```

Edit:
i kinda debbuged and finded that the behaviour is as follows:

1- open new tab

2- guard checks loggedIn variable, its false

3- guard redirects to login page

4- authService receives the logged user, loggedIn is set to true

5- get stuck in the login page with the user actually logged in

anyone has a hint to solve this?